# How to create a shortcut to some page and forcing it to be opened with Internet Explorer (not default browser)

Tags: internet-explorer, url, shortcut

Easy.

I have 2 gmails accounts and I want to open both at the same time.
I have Firefox as the default browser and of course, Internet Explorer.

So I want 2 desktop shorcuts to point to gmail.
So if I made a shortcut to http://gmail.com, it will be opened with Firefox (because it's the default browser), so that's ok for one account.
But I want another shortcut which also points to http://gmail.com but needs to be opened with IE.

Maybe something like "iexplore.exe " ???

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iexplore "url goes here"

Answer (score 3):

Silly boy =P

Just create a shortcut to iexplore.exe and add the url =P

**"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" www.gmail.com**

Answer (score 0):

Change the target of the shortcut to `iexplore.exe www.example.com`